# Getting "invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00" error when executing aws_s3.table_import_from_s3 command in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I am getting below error when executing :

```
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(   'test',  
'a,b,c,d,e',   
'(format csv)',  
'abc-ttt-dev',
   'outer/inner/Inbound/sample.csv',
   'us-east-1'
);
```

SQL Error [22021]: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
Where: COPY test, line 1
SQL statement "copy test (a,b,c,d,e) from '/rdsdbdata/extensions/aws_s3/amazon-s3-fifo-6826-20210708T140854Z-0' with (format csv)"

Just for information, Below query works perfectly fine.

```
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
   'test',
   'a,b,d,e',
   'DELIMITER ''|''', 
   'abc-ttt-dev',
   'outer/inner/Inbound/sample.txt',
   'us-east-1'
);
```

Table script is

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    a text not NULL,
    b text not NULL,
    c text not NULL,
    d text not NULL,
    e text not NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are NULL values in your csv file and that is the reason you get this error.

You can either pre process the file using lambda or refer to [Postgres error on insert - ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding “UTF8”: 0x00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347646/postgres-error-on-insert-error-invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8-0x0) for other workarounds.

Comment: There was some problem with my CSV file. I used another one and it worked well. Thanks for your help @Naman.